# I can't read Database file db

Tags: c, sqlite

I've database file `.db` of clinical chemistry analysers (RX IMOLA), it return folder data have many file .db, I'm used sqlite manager read file but fail.

[image]

Can you help me read this? Thanks.

Db files:

[image]

Comment: Are these really SQLite files?

Comment: i don't know , i'm try SQLite but it's fail, don't read